# incompatible types in assignment c

Tags: c, arrays, copying, incompatibletypeerror

I have following structs defined in my header file,

```
struct nl_packet {
      int seq;
      FRAMETYPE type;
      CnetAddr dest;
      CnetAddr src;
      uint32_t checksum;
      size_t length;
      char data[NL_MAXDATA];
    };


struct seq_Info  {

   int seqNum;
   size_t length;
   char data[NL_MAXDATA];

};

struct msg_Received {

   CnetAddr src;
   struct seq_Info seqInfo[BUFSIZ];
   int lastReceived;

};
```

and then in another file, I have the following assignment that comes with the "incompatible types in assignment error",

```
msgRec[i].seqInfo[j].data = packet.data;
```

I do have other statements like this in the same method but they work perfectly fine,

```
msgRec[i].seqInfo[j].seqNum = packet.seq;
msgRec[i].seqInfo[j].length = packet.length;
```

Even though both, data fields in nl_packet struct and seq_Info struct have the same type, then is this error coming up ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assigning arrays. You can not do that. You have to copy the array contents. You may do it like this:

`memcpy(msgRec[i].seqInfo[j].data, packet.data, sizeof(char)*NL_MAXDATA);`

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always one, as per the C specification, so it's never needed.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yeah, but... `#define char wchar`. Some people are strange.

Comment: If someone does that, they deserve the problems they will get! ;)

Comment: "strange" is not the right word for someone who would do that, and in C++ it would be undefined behavior: "A translation unit shall not #define or #undef names lexically identical to keywords"

Comment: Or `struct Data { char data[NL_MAXDATA];}; *(struct Data*)msgRec[i].seqInfo[j].data = *(struct Data*)packet.data;` ... of course, both of these copy too much data; one should only copy as much as was actually read.

Comment: You can't protect yourself from strange definitions (how about `#define sizeof(char) 7`?). But `sizeof` can improve clarity, and I'd use `sizeof(packet.data[0])`.